# Xpath for image src in flipcart

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I don't get Xpath for click on image in Flipkart website in mobiles section, realme shop now the image is there so I find XPath for that here I write code for that,

```
     package Test;

     import org.openqa.selenium.By;
     import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
     import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
     import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

     public class Fipcart {

     public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Software testing hydrabad\\Drivers\\New folder\\chromedriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.navigate().to("https://www.flipkart.com/");
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          System.out.println("Application Opened");
    
          Thread.sleep(3000);
    
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@class='_2IX_2-   VJZDxU']")).sendKeys("");         
          driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@class='_2IX_2- _3mctLh VJZDxU']")).sendKeys("");   
         driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='_2KpZ6l _2HKlqd _3AWRsL']")).click();    
        Thread.sleep(3000);     
    
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Mobiles")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);



      WebElement temp =   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'https://rukminim1.flixcart.com/flap/240/240/image/0f46b1ccbe7d0620.jpg?q=90')]"));
    temp.click();   
    
           }   
        }
```

I want XPath for realme image which has to click on there, here I find XPath for that.

[image]

Comment: Since all other attributes seem to be same, you can try your luck with these xpaths `//a[contains(@href,'POCO')]//img[@alt='Shop Now']`, 
`//a[contains(@href,'narzo')]//img[@alt='Shop Now']` etc...or you could have a mapping between image file name and brand store image and based on that mapping, select the relevant brand store image

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `Xpath` to identify the element and click.

```
WebElement temp =   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[./p[text()='Shop Now']]"));
temp.click();
```